# How do I use new `gpiod_export()` in the kernel space

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, gpio

In the kernel v4.14, we exported GPIOs from a kernel driver using the code below. After which, I could see all of the exported GPIOs in the user space with `cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio`

```c
static struct gpio ct_gen2_gpios[] __initdata = {
    {22, GPIOF_OUT_INIT_LOW, "gpo1" },
    {23, GPIOF_OUT_INIT_LOW, "gpo0" },
...
}
    gpio_request_array(my_gpios, ARRAY_SIZE(y_gpios));
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(y_gpios); i++) {
        gpio_export(ct_gen2_gpios[i].gpio, 1);  // THIS NO LONGER EXPORTS
    }
```

In the kernel v5.10, the legacy gpio.h is deprecated and this code no longer exports the gpios. I see the new

```c
int gpiod_export(struct gpio_desc *desc, bool direction_may_change);

struct gpio_desc {
    struct gpio_device  *gdev;
    unsigned long       flags;

    /* Connection label */
    const char      *label;
    /* Name of the GPIO */
    const char      *name;
[...]
};
```

but I can't find any examples of how to get or create the `struct gpio_desc`, specifically the `struct gpio_device *gdev` field.

How do I correctly export the GPIOs using the new descriptor interface?

Answer (score 1):

In the new code you must not use the legacy API. When converted to a new one, you can have a descriptor with help of the `gpiod_get()` family of calls, which may be issued at the `->probe()` stage in your driver.

Here is [the example](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/hsi/clients/nokia-modem.c#L112) of the existing driver in the Linux kernel.

Moreoever, the sysfs interface mustn't be used. I would suggest you to go away from calling even that function in your code.

Note, that legacy `gpio_export` [has been removed](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/brgl/linux.git/commit/?h=gpio/for-next&id=d74e316633e49f44756c23997fa071979a939405). This is pending change for v6.4-rc1.

Last but not least, this shows why upstreaming the code is important rather than having it in your sandbox only.

Comment: thanks for the pointer to the example.

I'm trying to add something similar to drivers/pinctrl/pinctrl-single and even the addition of a dev_info() statement causes the kernel to crash. No boot messages at all.
' dev_info(pcs->dev, "%i pins, size %u\n", pcs->desc.npins, pcs->size);
 dev_info(pcs->dev, "configuring gpio 2\n"); // my add
'

Comment: ^^^ has been resolved and not attributed to the answer